# Whether and How to edit this question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing-help

I found an intriguing yet bizarre question today that I think should be edited into a more useful form to benefit future readers: [Why should the observer pattern be deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619680/why-should-the-observer-pattern-be-deprecated)

If I can summarize the content of the question,

> I've had specific problems with the Observer Pattern. A paper I have not read says not to use the Observer Pattern. What's wrong with the Observer Pattern? I did read an article claiming that the paper I didn't read is nonsense.

The next day, the OP posted and accepted an answer by pasting a section of the paper, which presumably he read during the interim. Accounting for this answer, the original question seems to have been,

> Will someone read and summarize this paper for me?
>   Never mind, here's a relevant section from the (introduction of the) paper.

Taking the question in isolation, I have difficulty determining if the topic is dependency injection, guava, debugging, observers, patterns, Martin Oderski, all of these, or some of these. The accepted answer makes the question appear to be a straw man for the purpose of republishing the paper.

Assuming the paper (and therefore this answer) is interesting and valuable to the SO community, can the question be edited to reflect what the OP was obviously looking for? I'm curious to see how meta users would handle this... and "leave it alone" could be a valid response.

FYI, the paper can be found at https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/148043/files/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf since the original link is forbidden.

Comment: Vote to close as opinion based is likely best course of action. SO is generally against "give list of opinions about XXXXXX" - so I'm not sure how the question can be edited to be on-topic (especially without invalidating existing answers).